# Database design — how granular do I need to be?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I work in the publishing industry and I’m designing a mysql database to help me manage contracts. I have a set of core data tables – information about Authors, their respective Titles and Publishers – which I want to weave together to create contracts.

I’m new to mysql but I have been taking online courses, so I have a general grasp of data normalization. I’m having trouble on deciding how to design my contracts table.

**Information about the scope of data:**

- I’m working with approximately 500 authors, 1500 titles and 800
  publishers. These numbers will not increase dramatically.
- There are 3k+ contracts and likely 200 to be added per year

**Information about business rules:**

- Only one author/publisher per contract
- One contract can have multiple titles

**What it’s for:**

- A simple CRUD using php/html where I can add authors/titles/publishers and create new contracts.

**My question is:** How granular / atomized does my contract table need to be? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

I have worked on two solutions (see below). Based on what I know, option 1 is the most logical since I only need a many-to-many relationship between titles and contracts, but I have also read that it isn’t good practice to create a ‘main’ table since this doesn’t utilize the inherent relationality of mysql.

**Option 1 — one large contracts table**

- Here I’ve opted to relate the contracts to the authors and publishers
  by inserting foreign keys (FK) that connect to the respective primary
  keys (PK).

**Option 2 — granular contracts tables**

- Here I’ve opted to relate the contracts to the authors and publisher
  by way of the contract PK. Thus, the guiding principle here is the
  contract PK and not author/publisher PK.

[Click here for an ERD of both options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34est.jpg)

Thanks beforehand for any help or pointers!

Cheers

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Your "question" is 2 questions. And why is all that stuff there after you ask it? Define "granular" & "atomized". Requests for "advantages/disadvantages", " help or pointers" or "best" are off-topic as unfocused or seeking opinons. What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What are you asking re where you are 1st stuck following what published method? [ask] [help] [Re “Which is better”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) PS It's unclear what "a 'main' table" is or what "the inherent relationality" is or what you mean by it not being "utilized" by that design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 would only allow 1 author and 1 publisher per contract where as option 2 allows multiple authors and or publishers per contract. Clearly option 2 is more flexible, but do you need it?

If you don't need multiple authors or publishers per contract for the foreseeable future, then I would opt for option 1, otherwise go for option 2.